# Error with UI Table View + asynchronously loaded data

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4

I have a UI Table VIew with asynchronously loaded data from URL. for

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.notificationsResponse?.data?.count)!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let notification = notificationsResponse?.data![indexPath.row]
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! NotificationsViewCell
    cell.setNotification(notification: notification!)
    return cell
}

var notificationsResponse:NotificationsResponse?
```

I am getting the error like

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

In this line

```
return (self.notificationsResponse?.data?.count)!
```

And I don't know what's wrong with this. I am facing the issue, may be due to poor understand on swift

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: Avoid force unwrap (using `!`). From what I can guess, it's async, so the response is not here yet, so you'll get a crash. Do something like `return self.notificationsResponse?.data?.count ?? 0` instead.

Comment: optional chaining fails + unwrapping forcibly = crash.

Comment: Thanks @Larme This works fine.

Comment: Avoid force-unwrapping (`!`). This will make your app crash if you're not 100% there is a value. And when it comes to the asynchronous calls, make sure to update the values on the main thread.

Comment: Apart from the issue you are strongly discouraged from using a *notification response* as data source array.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the line where you use force unwrapping like this

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    guard let data = self.notificationsResponse?.data else { return 0 }
    return data.count
}
```

Edit: The Other answer is better actually haha. But guards are also a nice way to prevent force unwrapping.

Answer (score 0):

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return (self.notificationsResponse?.data?.count)!
}
```

please change

```
return self.notificationsResponse?.data?.count ?? 0
```